# Unable to edit Published Marketplace Listing

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

We have several published Google Marketplace Apps.  We need to modify the manifest of one of them.  Toady I attempted to do this and was met with the error message

"Permission Error
Sorry, you tried to do something you don't have permission for. To get back to the front page follow this link."

I know that we are all transitioning to Marketplace 2 but has Marketplace 1 been turned off already?

We need to be able to maintain our existing published apps until we are onto Marketplace 2...

Anybody know anything about this process?

Comment: I have raised this with the Marketplace support team and apparently edit access has been turned off to allow for and issue to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I have had confirmation from Google that the edit function was suspended for a bug fix.  They have said that it will be restored for Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked now and it is allowing Edit.